# magento: show disabled product

Tags: php, magento

I used this code:-

```
$category_id = 5;

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')    
->load($category_id)    
->getProductCollection()    
->addAttributeToSelect('*')    
->addAttributeToFilter('status',array(    
     'eq' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED)
);
```

it's doesn't work. it's show empty result.

Please let me know how to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you running it as an external script or inside the project ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution:

- First get a product collection
- Add a filter for disabled products
- Join the category table
- Filter the category table for specific category id's

This is a working example if you want to run the script outside magento:

```
require_once('app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
Mage::app();

// set category id
$categoryIds = [4]; // add child category id's if you want to support child categories also

$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('status', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED);
$productCollection->joinField('category_id','catalog/category_product','category_id','product_id=entity_id',null,'left')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => $categoryIds))
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$filteredProducts = $productCollection->getItems();

foreach ($filteredProducts as $product) {
    echo $product->getId() . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Inside magento:

```
// set category id
$categoryIds = [4]; // add child category id's if you want to support child categories also

$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('status', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED);
$productCollection->joinField('category_id','catalog/category_product','category_id','product_id=entity_id',null,'left')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => $categoryIds))
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$filteredProducts = $productCollection->getItems();
```

If you want to support multiple categories just add the id's to the array `$categoryIds`

If you have questions feel free to add a comment. If you got it working please let me know and add you magento version aswell. Thanks

Comment: You gave an alternative way of doing it, but the code in the question should give the same result

Comment: @RabeeAbdelWahab No, the code in the question isn't working ... Why would he ask if he got a working solution?

Comment: I ran it on an instance of Magento, and it is working. It could be an issue of where he is running it. Or it could be an issue of how the categories are associated with the products on his system. All am saying is that giving an alternative wont let people understand their issue, thats all